# LocationData cant be assigned

Tags: android, flutter

I copied from this website https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-places-location-search-with-map-view-using-flutter-1-0-alfian-losari-66cacb3bcc24
but i got some error such as the method isnt defined for the type and the locationdata cant be assigned to a variable of type[this is for location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ucQY.png)

map.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart';
import 'package:flutter_google_places/flutter_google_places.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart' as LocationManager;
import 'place_detail.dart';

const kGoogleApiKey = "AIzaSyCJXvgadNobevadeKKXvR-iqrCt87xmtpM";
GoogleMapsPlaces _places = GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);

// void main() {
//   runApp(MaterialApp(
//     title: "PlaceZ",
//     home: MapsDemo(),
//     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
//   ));
// }

class MapsDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MapsDemoState();
  }
}

class MapsDemoState extends State<MapsDemo> {
  final MapsDemoScaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  List<PlacesSearchResult> places = [];
  bool isLoading = false;
  String errorMessage;
 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget expandedChild;
    if (isLoading) {
      expandedChild = Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(value: null));
    } else if (errorMessage != null) {
      expandedChild = Center(
        child: Text(errorMessage),
      );
    } else {
      expandedChild = buildPlacesList();
    }

    return Scaffold(
        key: MapsDemoScaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("PlaceZ"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            isLoading
                ? IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.timer),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  )
                : IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                    onPressed: () {
                      refresh();
                    },
                  ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () {
                _handlePressButton();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: SizedBox(
                  height: 200.0,
                  child: GoogleMap(
                    onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: LatLng(0.0, 0.0),
                      zoom: 14.4746,
                    ),
                    // options: GoogleMapOptions(
                    //     myLocationEnabled: true,
                    //     cameraPosition:
                    //         const CameraPosition(target: LatLng(0.0, 0.0)))
                  )),
            ),
            Expanded(child: expandedChild)
          ],
        ));
  }

  void refresh() async {
    final center = await getUserLocation();

    mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
        target: center == null ? LatLng(0, 0) : center, zoom: 15.0)));
    getNearbyPlaces(center);
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async {
    mapController = controller;
    refresh();
  }

  Future<LatLng> getUserLocation() async {
    var currentLocation = <String, double>{};
    final location = LocationManager.Location();
    try {
      currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
      final lat = currentLocation["latitude"];
      final lng = currentLocation["longitude"];
      final center = LatLng(lat, lng);
      return center;
    } on Exception {
      currentLocation = null;
      return null;
    }
  }

  void getNearbyPlaces(LatLng center) async {
    setState(() {
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.errorMessage = null;
    });

    final location = Location(center.latitude, center.longitude);
    final result = await _places.searchNearbyWithRadius(location, 2500);
    setState(() {
      this.isLoading = false;
      if (result.status == "OK") {
        this.places = result.results;
        result.results.forEach((f) {
          final markerOptions = MarkerOptions(
              position:
                  LatLng(f.geometry.location.lat, f.geometry.location.lng),
              infoWindowText: InfoWindowText("${f.name}", "${f.types?.first}"));
          mapController.addMarker(markerOptions);
        });
      } else {
        this.errorMessage = result.errorMessage;
      }
    });
  }

  void onError(PlacesAutocompleteResponse response) {
    MapsDemoScaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text(response.errorMessage)),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _handlePressButton() async {
    try {
      final center = await getUserLocation();
      Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
          context: context,
          strictbounds: center == null ? false : true,
          apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
          onError: onError,
          mode: Mode.fullscreen,
          language: "en",
          location: center == null
              ? null
              : Location(center.latitude, center.longitude),
          radius: center == null ? null : 10000);

      showDetailPlace(p.placeId);
    } catch (e) {
      return;
    }
  }

  Future<Null> showDetailPlace(String placeId) async {
    if (placeId != null) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PlaceDetailWidget(placeId)),
      );
    }
  }

  ListView buildPlacesList() {
    final placesWidget = places.map((f) {
      List<Widget> list = [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4.0),
          child: Text(
            f.name,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle,
          ),
        )
      ];
      if (f.formattedAddress != null) {
        list.add(Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2.0),
          child: Text(
            f.formattedAddress,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle,
          ),
        ));
      }

      if (f.vicinity != null) {
        list.add(Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2.0),
          child: Text(
            f.vicinity,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
          ),
        ));
      }

      if (f.types?.first != null) {
        list.add(Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2.0),
          child: Text(
            f.types.first,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
          ),
        ));
      }

      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0, bottom: 4.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
        child: Card(
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              showDetailPlace(f.placeId);
            },
            highlightColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            splashColor: Colors.red,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: list,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }).toList();

    return ListView(shrinkWrap: true, children: placesWidget);
  }
}

class InfoWindowText {}
```

place_detail.dart

```
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

const kGoogleApiKey = "AIzaSyCJXvgadNobevadeKKXvR-iqrCt87xmtpM";
GoogleMapsPlaces _places = GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);

class PlaceDetailWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  String placeId;

  PlaceDetailWidget(String placeId) {
    this.placeId = placeId;
  }

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return PlaceDetailState();
  }
}

class PlaceDetailState extends State<PlaceDetailWidget> {
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  PlacesDetailsResponse place;
  bool isLoading = false;
  String errorLoading;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchPlaceDetail();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget bodyChild;
    String title;
    if (isLoading) {
      title = "Loading";
      bodyChild = Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          value: null,
        ),
      );
    } else if (errorLoading != null) {
      title = "";
      bodyChild = Center(
        child: Text(errorLoading),
      );
    } else {
      final placeDetail = place.result;
      final location = place.result.geometry.location;
      final lat = location.lat;
      final lng = location.lng;
      final center = LatLng(lat, lng);

      title = placeDetail.name;
      bodyChild = Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              child: SizedBox(
            height: 200.0,
            child: GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: center,
                zoom: 15.0,
              ),
              // onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              // options: GoogleMapOptions(
              //     myLocationEnabled: true,
              //     cameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: center, zoom: 15.0)),
            ),
          )),
          Expanded(
            child: buildPlaceDetailList(placeDetail),
          )
        ],
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: bodyChild);
  }

  void fetchPlaceDetail() async {
    setState(() {
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.errorLoading = null;
    });

    PlacesDetailsResponse place =
        await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(widget.placeId);

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        this.isLoading = false;
        if (place.status == "OK") {
          this.place = place;
        } else {
          this.errorLoading = place.errorMessage;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
    final placeDetail = place.result;
    final location = place.result.geometry.location;
    final lat = location.lat;
    final lng = location.lng;
    final center = LatLng(lat, lng);
    var markerOptions = MarkerOptions(
        position: center,
        infoWindowText: InfoWindowText(
            "${placeDetail.name}", "${placeDetail.formattedAddress}"));
    mapController.addMarker(markerOptions);
    mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        CameraPosition(target: center, zoom: 15.0)));
  }

  String buildPhotoURL(String photoReference) {
    return "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=${photoReference}&key=${kGoogleApiKey}";
  }

  ListView buildPlaceDetailList(PlaceDetails placeDetail) {
    List<Widget> list = [];
    if (placeDetail.photos != null) {
      final photos = placeDetail.photos;
      list.add(SizedBox(
          height: 100.0,
          child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: photos.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 1.0),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 100,
                      child: Image.network(
                          buildPhotoURL(photos[index].photoReference)),
                    ));
              })));
    }

    list.add(
      Padding(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0, bottom: 4.0),
          child: Text(
            placeDetail.name,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle,
          )),
    );

    if (placeDetail.formattedAddress != null) {
      list.add(
        Padding(
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0, bottom: 4.0),
            child: Text(
              placeDetail.formattedAddress,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
            )),
      );
    }

    if (placeDetail.types?.first != null) {
      list.add(
        Padding(
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0, bottom: 0.0),
            child: Text(
              placeDetail.types.first.toUpperCase(),
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
            )),
      );
    }

    if (placeDetail.formattedPhoneNumber != null) {
      list.add(
        Padding(
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0, bottom: 4.0),
            child: Text(
              placeDetail.formattedPhoneNumber,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button,
            )),
      );
    }

    if (placeDetail.openingHours != null) {
      final openingHour = placeDetail.openingHours;
      var text = '';
      if (openingHour.openNow) {
        text = 'Opening Now';
      } else {
        text = 'Closed';
      }
      list.add(
        Padding(
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0, bottom: 4.0),
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
            )),
      );
    }

    if (placeDetail.website != null) {
      list.add(
        Padding(
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0, bottom: 4.0),
            child: Text(
              placeDetail.website,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
            )),
      );
    }

    if (placeDetail.rating != null) {
      list.add(
        Padding(
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0, bottom: 4.0),
            child: Text(
              "Rating: ${placeDetail.rating}",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
            )),
      );
    }

    return ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: list,
    );
  }
}
```

[the Maps Demo that i called in the function when i clicked on icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBArP.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your getUserLocation function. The `location.getLocation()` method returns an object to `currentLocation` whose data type is `LocationData` however, your `currentLocation` object is of a `Map` type which causes the error.

```dart
Future<LatLng> getUserLocation() async {
    LocationData currentLocation = LocationData();
    final location = LocationManager.Location();
    try {
      currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
      final lat = currentLocation.latitude;
      final lng = currentLocation.longitude;
      final center = LatLng(lat, lng);
      return center;
    } on Exception {
      currentLocation = null;
      return null;
    }
  }
```